# UICollectionView doesn't reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The collection view in my app will reload data correctly at the first time. The next time I want the collection view to reload data(I set data source to nil before I call reloadData: method),but  the collection view cell still contains the old data.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionCellId forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init] ;
    }

    [self setupCellImage:cell indexPath:indexPath] ;

    return cell ;
}

-(void) setupCellImage:(UICollectionViewCell *) cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor] ;

    NSDictionary *mediaObject = popObjects[indexPath.row] ;
    NSLog(@"index.row:%d",indexPath.row) ;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init] ;
    [imageView clipsToBounds] ;
    imageView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds ;

    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black"] ;

    NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaObject[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]  ;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView   ] ;

    if (![[isPhotoLoadedDic valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath]] boolValue]) {
        [imageView setImageWithURL:imgUrl placeholderImage:placeholderImage completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
            // set the isPhotoLoadedDic
            if (image && !error) {
                [isPhotoLoadedDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath]] ;
                NSLog(@"row:%d loaded",indexPath.row)     ;
            } else{
                [isPhotoLoadedDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath]] ;
                NSLog(@"row:%d  fail to load this image",indexPath.row) ;
            }
        }]  ;
    }
}
```

requestLoading:request is the method where I set data source to nil

```
/**
 * Called just before the request is sent to the server.
 */
- (void)requestLoading:(IGRequest *)request {
    //reset objects before sending request
    isPhotoLoadedDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ;
    popObjects = nil ;
    [self.collectionView reloadData] ;
}
```

Can anyone helps me? Please.

Comment: Why do you set popObjects to nil? Did you try to send removeAllObjects message to popObjects instead of setting it to nil? Could you post numberOfRowsInSection method of your collection view datasource?

Comment: set it to nil is wrong?
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    NSLog(@"numberOfItemsInSection : %d",popObjects.count) ;
    return popObjects.count ;
}

Comment: It is not wrong in general, but it is a bit strange of setting it to nil when you could just empty your array. Set a breakpoint before return statement in numberOfItemsInSection and check console to be sure that printed number is 0 (and it should be since sending count  message to nil should return zero in your case). This way you will see if datasource method is getting called, and that it returns proper value (0 in this case).

Comment: Also you should remove following from your code: if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init] ;
    } because dequeue method will return reusable cell object if available, or it will create new one. You should not create cells on your own when using collection view (block inside if statement will never be called).